# Vector particles

Tags: vectors

A particle with position vector **r** moves so that its acceleration is given by $d^2/dt^2$ **r**=$d/dt$ **r** x (**b** x **r**) where **b** is a constant vector. Show that the following are also constant:

(a) the speed of the particle

(b) **b** dot (**r** x $d/dt$ **r**)

(c) **b** dot $d/dt$ **r** - $0.5*|$**b** x **r**$|^2$